# Leaking home water pressure regulator - how to know what repair kit?

Tags: plumbing, water

As you can see from the photo below, my pressure regulator is leaking. My research shows that I can buy repair kits but I cannot tell what brand/size kit is appropriate. I cannot find any markings on the body. Is there any way to determine what is needed before turning the water off and disassembling the unit? The pipes appear to be 1.25” diameter.

[image]